# Limites en un imageView no funcionan adecuadamente

Tags: android

tengo un imageview, en el cual manejo una imagen de 1600x1000 pixeles, estoy usando la clase matrix para escalarla(hacer ZOOM) y para desplazarla por la pantalla, el problema es que estoy tratando de establecer limites para que la imagen no se pierda y los limites no funcionan adecuadamente, a veces funcionan y otras veces dejan ver una parte de la pantalla que no corresponde a la imagen, esto sucede cuando desplazo la imagen de lado a lado <- ->; como nota adicional la imagen se encuentra en la carpeta drawable-nodpi

```
package sdf.myapplication;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomInZoomOut extends AppCompatActivity
{

ImageView im;
Matrix matrix =new Matrix();
Float scale=1f,scale2;
ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
float posX=0.0f,posY=0.0f,resX,resY,v1x=0,v2x=0,lasx=0,lasy=0;
Point xy=new Point();
boolean stat=false;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom_in_zoom_out);


    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    SGD= new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        display.getSize(xy);
        resX=xy.x;
        resY=xy.y;
    }else{
        resX=display.getWidth();
        resY=display.getHeight();
    }
    scale2=resX/1600;
    Log.e("RES",Float.toString(scale2));
    scale=scale2;
    matrix.setScale(scale,scale);


}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scale=scale*detector.getScaleFactor();
        scale= Math.max(scale2,Math.min(scale,5f));
        matrix.setScale(scale,scale);
        im.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        v1x=0;
        v2x=0;
        return true;
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float v1=0,v2=0;

    SGD.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            v1=event.getX()-posX;
            v2=event.getY()-posY;

            if(!stat){
                v1x=v1x+v1;
                v2x=v2x+v2;

                //if para el eje X
                if (v1x < (-1600 * scale + resX)) {
                    v1x = -1600 * scale + resX;
                    v1=0;
                } else if (v1x > 0) {
                    v1x = 0;
                    v1=0;
                }

                //if para el eje Y
                if(v2x < (-1000 * scale + resY)) {
                    v2x = -1000 * scale + resY;
                    v2=0;
                } else if (v2x > 0) {
                    v2x = 0;
                    v2=0;
                }

                matrix.postTranslate(v1,v2);

            }



            im.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            stat=true;
            v1x=0;
            v2x=0;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            posY=event.getY()-v2;
            posX=event.getX()-v1;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            stat=false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            lasx=v1;
            lasy=v2;
            break;

    }
    Log.e("v1",Float.toString(v1));


    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

existe una manera sutil de hacer zoom a las imagenes. Esta te entrega el efecto típico de acercamiento, desplazamiento, alejamiento, etc.

Primero Defines en el XML tu imagen

```
<DondeGuardasteLaClase.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewimagenrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 />
```

Y Esto funciona con la siguiente clase. Por lo que debes crear la siguiente clase en tu proyecto para que funcione.

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

La puedes descargar y pegar en tu proyecto. O simplemente puedes crear una clase de nombre TouchImageView en tu proyecto y copiarle todo el código dentro. En ambas tendras que modificar el package y cambiarlo por el de tu app.